# why do Lycoming piston engine aircraft operate at 75% best power?

Tags: aircraft-performance, general-aviation, engine

What happens to the remaining 25%, is the remaining 25% lost due to friction?

Comment: Your question needs clarification. Which Lycoming engine are you asking about? Why do you think it can only operate at 75% power?

Comment: Do you run your car's engine continuously at redline RPM?

Comment: Lycoming O-320-D3G. I'm asking why the POH says to operate at 75% best power and what are the reasons why its set at this percentage?

Comment: @BrainL sorry about the downvotes.  This is actually a good question if it  refers to the POH performance charts of a recreational aircraft with a piston engine such as a Cessna 172.  In *cruising level flight*  full throttle will be hopelessly fuel inefficient and may cause the aircraft to *exceed safe speed limits*.  Also, as you climb, 100% power cannot be generated due to thinner air.  So, reading your POH (+10 for that) keep in mind the performance envelope (Vne, Vsafe manuvering, Vflaps extended) and remember "55, 65, 75%" power at given altitudes is for TAS and gallons per hour cruising

Comment: If you climb, give it all you've got (watch for overheating, and *density altitude*).

Comment: This question *has* potential, and with an *extensive* rewrite, it could be a very good one. The OP's comment being incorporated would get it part-way there. But as it stands, it just isn't there. Voting to leave closed, but willing to re-open if further edits improve what's being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let's assume sea level operation. At 75% power, the engine is burning only 75% of its maximum fuel flow rate, and the remaining 25% of the engine capacity is "off line"- but available at any time by pushing the propeller speed control up to full fine pitch (for a plane with a constant-speed prop) or by opening the throttle all the way (in a plane with a prop fixed at fine pitch).

Note that depending on the engine it may be limited to full power for perhaps only three minutes total time, to prevent the engine from overheating. So you use full power for three minutes during takeoff and initial climbout and then pull the power back to cruise power at the 3-minute mark.

Answer (score 2):

Light aircraft manufacturers typically use 75% power as a normal cruising power. There is really no set reason for this 75% figure. It is just a convenient convention that most light aircraft manufacturers use.

Part of the reason for this is that a normally aspirated (non-turbocharged) piston engine can only produce 100% rated power at sea level on a standard day. (15C and 29.92). This means that in most cases 100% rated power is not available for takeoff.